# Workflow doesn't appear when I apply retention

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have created a custom list and workflow to send email reminders. However, when I tried to apply retention on the item and select 'start a workflow', it says there's no workflow associated with the list.

What am I missing here? The workflow is running ok.

Comment: can you add screenshot? is the first iteration of WF successfully finished?

Comment: can't add the image, but anyway, yes first iteration of workflow was completed. It's when I add retention stage and choose the action 'start a workflow', it says an error  "There are no workflows associated with the list. Select another action."